# Image file from Silverlight to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, stream, byte

I'm trying to upload a photo from a Silverlight client to a server, using a WCF service.

The method called by the client is void UpdatePicture(Stream image);
This method on the client side, appears as UpdatePicture(byte[] array), so I created a converter (the input stream is a FileStream from OpenFileDialog.File.OpenRead())

```
private byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] array = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
        return array;
    }
```

The converter seems to work well.

On the WCF side, I have to save the stream to a file. I use this :

```
public void UpdatePicture(Stream image)
    {
        if (SelectedUser == null)
            return;
        if (File.Exists(image_path + SelectedUser.sAMAccountName + ".jpg"))
        {
            File.Delete(image_path + SelectedUser.sAMAccountName + ".jpg");
        }

        using (FileStream file = File.Create(image_path + SelectedUser.sAMAccountName + ".jpg"))
        {
            DataManagement.CopyStream(image, file);
        }
    }
```

to copy the Stream to the FileStream, I use this :

```
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
```

The file is created as expected, the size is ok, but the image is not displayed by the PhotoViewer ou any other program.

Does somebody knows why ? Any help would be very appreciated :)

EDIT :

Something really strange :

I created a WCF method GetWCFBytes(byte[] array) which returns the parameter without doing anything.
If use StreamToByteArray to pass a stream to this method as a byte array, and set the result to a Image via a BitmapImage with a MemoryStream, it displays a blank image.

If I take the OpenFileDialog's stream, convert it to a byte array, create a new MemoryStream from this array, and set my BitmapImage with it : the image is ok.

Does WCF use some magic against streams and byte arrays ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `CopyStream` method makes sure to keep reading from the input stream until it doesn't get anything more. Your `StreamToByteArray` method doesn't. Are you sure you're converting the entire stream on the client, rather than just the first *x* bytes followed by zeroes?

```
private byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] array = new byte[stream.Length];
    int index = 0, length = 0;
    while ((length = stream.Read(array, index, array.Length - index)) > 0)
    {
        index += length;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. The file has the same size whether I use the while + Read or not.
I think that this method is ok, because if I convert back the byte array to a stream, I can still use it in a BItmapImage and it displays correctly in the Image control.

So I think that something is wrong on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, and it did have nothing to do with WCF !

The problem is that I convert my OpenFileDialog result on confirm button on in my ViewModel.
I don't know why but if I do the conversion in the method which called the openfiledialog, the byte array isn't corrupted and all work fine.

Thanks.